# Wpf. Color a rectangle depending on the object property from array

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, itemscontrol

I want to color a rectangle depending on the object property from array.
I use

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Ports}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle Width="10" Height="10" Margin="2,3,0,0">
                <Rectangle.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
                       <Style.Triggers>
                           <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Ports[].Link}" Value="false">
                               <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"></Setter>
                           </DataTrigger>
                           <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Ports[].Link}" Value="true">
                               <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Green"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>                                                                
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Rectangle.Style>
            </Rectangle>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
 </ItemsControl>
```

How to Binding to Value field `Port.Link` from Array `Ports` ?
`<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Ports[].Link}" Value="false">`

Comment: Try setting Two way mode for binding

Comment: two way is the default i believe anyway

Comment: it's not working. How to write here `Path=Ports[].Link`. I think it is not correct

Comment: how is it supposed to work out which index of the array to use?

Comment: @JohnB I don't know :) but I should paint dynamic rectangles and color their different color.

Comment: maybe use converter here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Link}" Value="true">` without `Ports[]`